# How to go about creating points at river confluences?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, rivers, lines-to-points

Working in ArcGIS 10.4. I have a rivers dataset, and I want to create a point wherever two rivers meet (tributaries join with other rivers, etc.). I tried the Intersect tool, but I think that tool requires more than one input dataset. I have Network Analyst, if that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Could creating a geometric network solve the problem? (ArcCatalog > Geodatabase > Feature dataset > Geometric network). Junctions will be created automatically at the intersections of the rivers."

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/21850

Spatial ecology plugin does it simply as well. The tool is *isectfeatures* 
(Intersect Features)

http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/isectfeatures.htm

If you specify a single input feature data source, then it calculates intersections between geometries within that dataset.

Or just do as Richard states.

Answer (score 12):

The Intersect tool does not require two inputs.  The help for [How Intersect (Analysis) works](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/Analysis_Tools/how_intersect_analysis_works.htm) says "Intersect can run with a single input.  In this case, instead of discovering intersections between the features from the different feature classes or layers, it will discover the intersections between features within the single input. This can be useful to discover polygon overlap and line intersections (as points or lines)."

You have to be sure to change the output type to Points to get the intersection points created, since otherwise the tool will try to find only overlapping line segments.

Comment: Good answer richard, I thought it needed two as well.

Comment: I had tried the Intersect tool with only the one input, and I did change the output type to points. The tool completes but returns a "Warning 000117- empty output". ArcGIS Help says this might be due to extents excluding all features, but my extents are fine. The input shapefile is definitely populated also.

Comment: First try selecting the lines in a layer and using that as an input.  Sometimes that makes a difference (even if it shouldn't).  If that does not  work you should try the Extend tool in the Editing Tollbox on a few selected segments that ought to intersect each other to makes sure that they topologically touch.  If that fixes those lines, you may want to put the data in a dataset in a geodatabase and create a topology with the Must Not have Dangles rule and Must Not Intersect or Touch Interior rule to use topology to help you identify the places where you need to extend and split the lines.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing you might try after you've created a correct network is the feature vertices to points tool, with either start, end or both ends option (just in case your stream network is not correctly digitized). This tool is located in the Data Management -> Features toolbox.